# How to perform boxing in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, casting

I'm trying to understand how casting works in Scala. Here is the example:

```
object Main extends App {
    val ai: Array[Any] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    val ar: Array[AnyRef] = ai.map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
}
```

And it works fine. https://ideone.com/6PerTR

Now let's rewrite it as follows:

```
object Main extends App {
    val ai: AnyRef = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    val ar: Array[AnyRef] = ai.asInstanceOf[Array[Any]].map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
}
```

It does not work. It fails with `ClassCastException` now https://ideone.com/JbOQbb. Why? I thought adding cast is enough here? Why does the first example work?

How to make it work in the second case if we are casting `AnyRef` to `Array[Any]` first? How to add boxing here?

***UPD:*** I also tried:

```
object Main extends App {
    val ai: AnyRef = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    val aii: Array[Any] = ai.asInstanceOf[Array[Any]]
    val ar: Array[AnyRef] = aii.map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
}
```

But got `ClassCastException` https://ideone.com/ZcgT6x. It looks very similar to the first example though. How to cast `aii` to `Array[AnyRef]` in the case?

Comment: What is your motivation? Casting should be avoided, whenever possible. It's a code smell.

Comment: @userunknown Porting java code... Trying to avoid rewriting it completely.

Comment: And what does that Java code look like?

Comment: @userunknown It performs `instance of` agains `Object`. If the type is `Object[]` then we checks the first element in the `Object[]`. If it's `Number` then we cast all its elements to `Number`. Too many casts around pretty complicated logic. I decided first port it and then this smell out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: The first snippet works because the autoboxing takes place already when the array is generated. The second snippet does not work, because the created array is an `Array[Int]`.

---

Even though `Int` is subtype of `Any`, an `Array[Int]`
is *not* a subtype of `Array[Any]`. Therefore, when you write

```
scala> val ai: Array[Any] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
ai: Array[Any] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

this is essentially equivalent to

```
val ai: Array[Any] = Array[Any](1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

so that all integers are already boxed. The result is:

```
scala> ai.getClass
res0: Class[_ <: Array[Any]] = class [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

that is, your `ai` is essentially an `Array[Object]` right from the beginning.

The crucial difference in the second snippet is that even though `Array[Int]`
is not subtype of `Array[Any]`, it definitely *is* a subtype of `AnyRef`, so
no autoboxing takes place:

```
scala> val ai: AnyRef = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
ai: AnyRef = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

scala> ai.getClass
res2: Class[_ <: AnyRef] = class [I
```

as you can see, the `AnyRef` is an `int`-array with unboxed ints.

If you now try to cast an array of unboxed ints into an `Array[Any]`, you
get a class cast exception.

You could fix your second example by enforcing immediate autoboxing like this:

```
object Main extends App {
    val ai: AnyRef = Array[Any](1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    val ar: Array[AnyRef] = 
      ai.asInstanceOf[Array[Any]].map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
}
```

or alternatively you could cast your array to the right type, namely `Array[Int]`:

```
object Main extends App {
    val ai: AnyRef = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    val ar: Array[AnyRef] =
      ai.asInstanceOf[Array[Int]].map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
}
```

Comment: Another good Scala answer from Andrey. I appreciate your knowledge and the quality of your explanations. :)

Comment: @DonBranson Thanks for your response, I hope the quality is getting better gradually :)

Answer (score 2):

As there is no representation of `Any` type at bytecode level, both `Array[Any]` and `Array[AnyRef]` require the elements to be boxed. So, when trying to cast from `Array[Int]` to `Array[Any]`, we're actually casting from `[I` to `[java/lang/Object;` which results as an exception.

The only general solution is specially handling arrays of each primitive type, which can be done quite easily using a `WrappedArray`:

```
val ai: AnyRef = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
val ar: Array[AnyRef] = collection.mutable.WrappedArray.make(ai).toArray
```